# JavaFX App Screen Black and Unresponsive After Remote Desktop Session (RDP)

Tags: java, javafx, windows-10, screen, rdp

I'm running a JavaFX application on a Windows 10 Desktop. When I login to the desktop via remote desktop [RDP] and then login using local machine the JavaFX GUI becomes black and unresponsive as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

The GUI is black and unresponsive (no buttons or GUI elements are visible). Nothing I do (such as enlarging or minimizing screen) solved the issue. **I am forced to terminate the program every time this occurs.**

Moreover, there's no other process running in on the machine that might "freeze" the GUI. It simply happens every time I login to Windows 10 computer via RDP (using a laptop) while the JavaFX App is running. As soon as I logout and log back in, the problem occurs. Notice, the only part that does not "freeze" and is still visible is the *APP:* name in the top left side of app header. Also, no other app (including Eclipse as seen in the screenshot above) is suffering from this problem - besides for the **JavaFX Application Screen**.

What's causing this issue?

Thanks